# Mongodb session store in Expressjs 4

Tags: mongodb, session, express

In express 3 I use `connect-mongo` for session store.

```
var mongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express);
```

But after I switched to express 4 it doesn't work. I got this error:

```
Error: Most middleware (like session) is no longer bundled with Express and must be       installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.
```

I see connect has been removed from express 4. How can I continue use this or are there any good libs that I can use for express 4. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to install the express-session package separately now. It can be found at https://github.com/expressjs/session

Use the following commands to get up and running:

```
npm install --save express-session cookie-parser
```

and then in your server.js file:

```
var express = require('express'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    expressSession = require('express-session'),
    MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(expressSession),
    app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressSession({
     secret: 'secret',
     store: new MongoStore(),
     resave: false,
     saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

And enjoy

Comment: I see some `Unexpected token -` here.

Comment: I think it was invalid variable names. I updated my answer to reflect better variable names.

Comment: change this line MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express-session) to MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(expressSession)

Answer (score 1):

You can still use [connect-mongo](http://kcbanner.github.com/connect-mongo/) in expressjs 4. Example from the README:

```
var session    = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

app.use(session({
    secret: settings.cookie_secret,
    store: new MongoStore({
      db : settings.db,
    })
  }));
```

Comment: bower is for client-side packages like backbone, underscore, jquery, bootstrap, foundation, etc.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I've removed the mention to bower. Moreover I've added an example, because I still think is important for people having the same question to know that you can still use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the 'new' session middleware https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware

Comment: It seems I have to implement mongodb session store myself.

Answer (score -1):

check this module and example codes.

https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-sessions

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect();

app.use(express.session({
    secret: 'a4f8071f-c873-4447-8ee2',
    cookie: { maxAge: 2628000000 },
    store: new (require('express-sessions'))({
        storage: 'mongodb',
        instance: mongoose, // optional
        host: 'localhost', // optional
        port: 27017, // optional
        db: 'test', // optional
        collection: 'sessions', // optional
        expire: 86400 // optional
    })
}));
```

Comment: No this is the old express version.